# WiFi connection beetween a few devices and Android tablet

Tags: java, android, wifi

I need some theoretical knowledge about this kind of connection. I've got a router with open wifi. I have also two (this number can change up to 15) devices connected to that network and one android tablet.

The main point is to show on a tablet data from these 2 devices at the same time.

So, what's the best idea to develop that idea on Android(API 2.3)? Using sockets or wifi connection( each in one thread)? Thanks for all solutions. Cheers.

Comment: depends on what exactly you are trying to accomplish, unless you elaborate more there is no way we can answer what the "best" one will be.

Comment: ok, maybe "best" isn't good word. I need any possible solution for that.